# Is there a way to create groups from a dataframe considering that groups should be balanced by the average of their values?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to create N groups from a dataframe, but considering that the values of the groups should be close to the average.

This is the head of my dataframe:

[image: cluster_map]

which has 61 rows. And I want the average of each group in the 'cluster' column to be similar to the rest of the groups.

What I have tried is to split the dataframe with:

```
df_out = np.array_split(cluster_map, 14)
```

but I get this at the output

```
df_out = np.array_split(cluster_map, 14)
print df_out[0]['cluster'].mean()
print df_out[1]['cluster'].mean()
print df_out[2]['cluster'].mean()
print df_out[3]['cluster'].mean()
print df_out[4]['cluster'].mean()
print df_out[5]['cluster'].mean()
print df_out[6]['cluster'].mean()
print df_out[7]['cluster'].mean()
print df_out[8]['cluster'].mean()
print df_out[9]['cluster'].mean()
print df_out[10]['cluster'].mean()
print df_out[11]['cluster'].mean()
print df_out[12]['cluster'].mean()
print df_out[13]['cluster'].mean()

[Out]
    1.2
    1.6
    1.4
    1.0
    1.2
    1.5
    3.75
    0.5
    1.25
    2.0
    1.0
    2.25
    1.0
    1.0
```

where the means of the 'cluster' column are not balanced. I want these values to be as close as possible to each other and try to have similar number of elements in each group.

Is there any way to do this on a dataframe?.

Thanks :)

Comment: [Please do not post code nor data-frames as images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks similar to stratified splitting, but you need 14 splits. 
Try this!

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=14)

cluster_map['group_id'] = 0
group_id =0

for _, test_index in kf.split(cluster_map,cluster['cluster']):
    cluster_map.loc[test_index,'group_id'] = group_id
    group_id += 1
```